# Audio Frequency in Android

Tags: android, audio, frequency, android-sdk-2.1

I have written a code for getting frequency of audio.
I have used Zero Crossing algorithm to convert short array into frequency(int).
It works fine.
Whenever I play 2500Hz Audio Frequency in my PC It gives me perfect value.
 e.g. 2500Hz=1400
If I play **2500Hz** Audio Frequency for **10sec** it gives me **1400** for **10sec**.
So I can say that it works fine without any problem. There is no any issue with code.

But Now My problem is that whenever I change Device the output also changed.
e.g above output I get when I use **Samsung GT-i5700.(Android 2.2)**
 But When I use **Micro-max A-60(Android 2.1)** It gives me output like that **2500Hz=771**.

**I can't find the reason,why output is changed when device is changed?

How can I solve this?

Is there any connection between android version and audio frequency?**


**Note:**
I have cable which gives output from PC speaker to Devices MIC. So I can play Tone in PC and send it directly to Device MIC.

Comment: Maybe the sample rates are different on the two devices ? Note however that using zero crossings is a very unreliable way of measuring frequency - it only really works for pure tones (sinusoids) with zero noise. Adding hysteresis can help a little, but it's never going to be a great solution.

Comment: please paste your code here, we want to see it in order ti help ypu, if you already has it please share it with us, please
thanks VanPersie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the calculated frequency changes when you change handset then I would expect that your code is in fact NOT fine. Have you tried a third handset and observed if the results it gives match one of the previous 2 handsets?

If you are looking for potentially more accurate solutions (saying a 2500Hz tone outputs 1400 seems odd to me) look at [How do you analyse the fundamental frequency of a PCM or WAV sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268/music-how-do-you-analyse-the-fundamental-frequency-of-a-pcm-or-wac-sample) for options.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [implementation](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/audio/processing/ZeroCrossing.java) on Android, I have found that it rarely gets the correct frequency as well. However, it does produce a "consistent" value when it is hearing a tone versus random speech, which is still useful.