# How do I analyze volume, pitch and speed of a .wav file in Java?

Tags: java, wav, analysis, waveform

So, I'm trying to remake Vib Ribbon: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehdymXc0epY
The input will be a .wav file, and I haven't the slightest idea of how to analyze it and create thresholds for volume and pitch that would create different obstacles- I've been pointed to Fourier transforms, which I don't understand. Can someone point me to a waveform analysis class that would work for this situation and give me an idea of how to start? I haven't been able to get my hands on source code for things like AudioSurf and music visualizers.

Why java, you might ask? I'm taking an introductory Java class, so no other language will work.

Comment: You'd need a special library. You could try this: http://blog.datasingularity.com/?p=53

Comment: Thanks- very helpful link, although I wasn't able to use it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Sound Viewer Tool](https://github.com/ljvillanueva/Sound-Viewer-Tool) for this, albeit in another language (Python) and for another class project. If the following is added to svt.py:

```
def processWav(filename, channel):
    """
    filename: path to a wav file
    Channel: 1 for left, 2 for right
    Returns centroids, frequencies, volumes
    """
    #open file
    audio_file = audiolab.sndfile(filename, 'read')
    #should be length of audiofile in seconds * 60. will fix this later
    import contextlib
    import wave
    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(filename, 'r')) as f:
        frames = f.getnframes()
        rate = f.getframerate()
        duration = frames / float(rate)
    duration *= 30 #30 data points for every second of audio yay
    duration = int(duration) #can only return an integer number of frames so yeah
    #print duration
    #Not really samples per pixel but I'll let that slide
    samples_per_pixel = audio_file.get_nframes() / float(duration)
    #some rule says this frequency has to be half of the sample rate
    nyquist_freq = (audio_file.get_samplerate() / 2) + 0.0
    #fft_size stays 4096
    processor = AudioProcessor(audio_file, 2048, channel, numpy.hanning)

    centroids = []
    frequencies = []
    volumes = []

    for x in range(duration):
        seek_point = int(x * samples_per_pixel)
        next_seek_point = int((x + 1) * samples_per_pixel)
        (spectral_centroid, db_spectrum) = processor.spectral_centroid(seek_point)
        peaks = processor.peaks(seek_point, next_seek_point)      
        centroids.append(spectral_centroid)
        frequencies.append(db_spectrum)
        volumes.append(peaks)

    #print "Centroids:" + str(centroids)
    #print "Frequencies:" + str(frequencies)
    #print "Volumes:" + str(volumes)

    #convert volumes[] from peaks to actual volumes
    for i in range(len(volumes)):
        volumes[i] = abs(volumes[i][0]) + abs(volumes[i][1])
    #round frequencies to save resources
    for i in range(len(frequencies)):
        for j in range(len(frequencies[i])):
            frequencies[i][j] = round(frequencies[i][j], 4)
    return centroids, frequencies, volumes
```

analysis can easily be done with wav files. The centroids represent the timbre of the music - a weighted average of the frequencies, they indicate the overall brightness at any point in time.

The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154084/how-to-extract-frequency-out-of-wav-sample-data) was a huge help to me in understanding FFTs/signal processing/digital sound representation.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Praat script (Praat is available for download [here](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)) to produce an output file containing the information you need and then read that txt file with your java program.

There are probably also external libraries, like @Gareth said.